# How to play local multiplayer games with friends remotely (Parsec alternative)?

Tags: games, alternative, lutris

I'd like to play some epic games store games (I'm using lutris) with friends. Before switching to linux (I'm using PopOS, not exactly Ubuntu, but mostly the same thing) I was using Parsec, but as it doesn't support hosting and can only be used as a client so it's not a viable option anymore.

I tried Zoom and it worked ok, but latency was just a bit bad (still usable for the types of games we play) and I'd like controller support. I'd prefer not to use port forwarding if possible and support for more than 1 client.

Main game I had in mind is Overcooked if that helps.

Comment: Only Ubuntu and official flavors of Ubuntu (https://ubuntu.com/download/flavours) are on-topic here, refer to https://askubuntu.com/help/on-topic where you'll find other SE sites where you question will be welcome if you don't want to use a Pop forum. (*One advantage of Ubuntu is it's many support options, you opted for Pop OS so take advantage of it's support options, or SE Unix & Linux*)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only thing you can use is Steam Remote Play. You can add games that's not on your libray of Steam to make it work.